# Can I use my Ubuntu for network administration?

Tags: networking, server

Can you please name some tools that will help me analyze and administrate network and server?

Comment: Your English is very good :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very good tool to use is [NMap](http://nmap.org/). You can install it easily with :

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

Is is useful for security purposes to find if any unwanted ports on a computer are open, it can also be used to check IP addresses *(I find it useful when the router resets and i
I need to find the IP address of my network printer.)*

A command that would scan for a computers Operating System *(`-O`)*, as well as script, version and trace route scanning.:

```
sudo nmap -A -O IP_ADDRESS
```

or for more informative output *(verbose - `-v`)*:

```
sudo nmap -A -O -vvv IP_ADDRESS
```

---

For example, if I run this:

```
sudo nmap -A -O -vvv 192.168.1.6
```

it shows this for some Network Attached Storage *(Closed)*:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-12-22 16:32 GMT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.6
Host is up (0.00037s latency).
Not shown: 991 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE      VERSION
21/tcp   closed ftp
22/tcp   open   ssh  
2049/tcp closed nfs
MAC Address: **:**:**:**:**:** (MANUFACTURER-OF-NETWORKING-HARDWARE)
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 2.6.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6
OS details: Linux 2.6.9 - 2.6.27
Network Distance: 1 hop

TRACEROUTE
HOP RTT     ADDRESS
1   0.37 ms 192.168.1.6


OS and Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 13.24 seconds
```

This shows that it currently only has the `ssh` port open to access, on port `22`, with the `ftp` and `nfs` ports available, but closed, on `21` and `2049` ports. An example for  use for this is that you could see if you had ssh remote access on a machine which you did not want to be accessed.

<sup>Yes, I have edited some sort-of-secret info out of the above output - including `MAC Address: **:**:**:**:**:** (MANUFACTURER-OF-NETWORKING-HARDWARE)`</sup>

There is also a graphical interface for Nmap you can use, called [Zenmap](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/zenmap/)

Hope this helps [image: smiley]

Comment: OK IT WORKED FOR ME :)